# Codeigniter: unable to get the fields value using join

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, join

I have a foreign key Id of third table , eg.(having `thirdsubmenu_id` of `thirdsubmenu` table) . i want  to get the `menu_name` name from my parent table `mainmenu`  .  *Please see   below my database table structure for complete details*

**DATABASE STRUCTURE**

```
 1)Table: mainmenu
    ---------------
     mainmenu_id   PK(primary key)
     menu_name     ..... 

    2)Table: submenu
    -------------------
     submenu_id     PK
     mainmenu_id    FK (foreign key refrences mainmenu table)
     submenu_name   ..... 


    3)Table: thirdsubmenu
    --------------------
      thirdsubmenu_id     PK
      submenu_id          FK (foreign key refrences submenu table)
      thirdsubmenu_name     ........
```

I tried the below code for getting `menu_name` from my `mainmenu` table but i am getting the error.

```
 //---------------------------get Main Menu Name by thirdsubmenu_id-----------------------------------
function getMainMenuNameOfSubmenu($thirdsubmenu_id)
{
    $this->load->database();   
    $this->db->select('*');
    $query=$this->db->join('mainmenu', 'mainmenu.mainmenu_id = submenu.mainmenu_id', 'left')
           ->join('submenu', 'submenu.submenu_id = thirdsubmenu.submenu_id', 'left')
           ->get_where('thirdsubmenu',array('thirdsubmenu_id'=>$thirdsubmenu_id));  

    return $query->row('menu_name');   
}
```

**Error I am getting is:**

```
    A Database Error Occurred

    Error Number: 1054

    Unknown column 'submenu.mainmenu_id' in 'on clause'

    SELECT * FROM (`thirdsubmenu`) LEFT JOIN `mainmenu` ON `mainmenu`.`mainmenu_id` = `submenu`.`mainmenu_id` LEFT JOIN `submenu` ON `submenu`.`submenu_id` = `thirdsubmenu`.`submenu_id` WHERE `thirdsubmenu_id` = '17'

    Filename: D:\xampp\htdocs\system\database\DB_driver.php

    Line Number: 330
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach in creating parent-child relationship is not correct.
Consider having 10, 20 or 50 submenus. What would you do? Create a table for each one of them?

You could hold all the relationship in a single table and just add a column that refers to each menu's parent. Then with a recursive function you could get all the tree of the menu.

Now about your question the problem is that you are joining `thirdsubmenu` with `mainmenu` and then you refer to `` submenu`.`mainmenu_id `` which is a column from `submenu`
That's why you see the error.

Try this code:

```
function getMainMenuNameOfSubmenu($thirdsubmenu_id)
{
    $this->load->database();   
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('mainmenu');
    $this->db->join('submenu', 'mainmenu.mainmenu_id = submenu.mainmenu_id', 'left')
           ->join('thirdsubmenu', 'submenu.submenu_id = thirdsubmenu.submenu_id', 'left')
           ->where('thirdsubmenu.thirdsubmenu_id = "' . $thirdsubmenu_id . '"'); 
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->row('menu_name');   
}
```

Comment: i tried your code .But  getting error `Not unique table/alias: 'thirdsubmenu'....`

Comment: Edited the where clause. Check again.

Comment: Sorry , after your edit ,still error: `syntax error` near in this line `->where('thirdsubmenu.thirdsubmenu_id = "' . $thirdsubmenu_id . '"'));`

Comment: Solved, one extra bracket was there here `"'));`  . I knew my table structure is not good, after I created all the codes. Though this is small apps, so i need only 4 sub menus. But for the next time i will do same as you suggested. Thank you